# Remote Runtime Exception while freeing up resources

Tags: java, clob

I have below code in my application

```
finally {
   Utility.close(conn, rs, stmt);
   freeclob(xml);   
}
```

I added the freeclob method to free up the clob object. However after adding this I am getting

09 Sep 2014 07:01:45,550 ERROR [Error.freeclob()] freeclob: error in java.sql.free weblogic.rmi.extensions.RemoteRuntimeException: Unexpected Exception

Q1:Can someone please let me know the possible reason for that.

Also when I check java documentation for clob's free method I found this:

```
void java.sql.Clob.free() throws SQLException
```

This method frees the Clob object and releases the resources the resources that it holds. The object is invalid once the free method is called.

Q2: my question : What is the meaning of releases the resources here.

Comment: finally {
   Utility.close(conn, rs, stmt);
   freeclob(xml);   
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order you do these in: free the clob first, then close everything else. Put the Utility.close method in a separate finally block so that if an exception is thrown by freeclob it won't result in the close method call getting skipped.

The [API documentation for java.sql.Clob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html) says:

> By default drivers implement a Clob object using an SQL locator(CLOB), which means that a Clob object contains a logical pointer to the SQL CLOB data rather than the data itself. A Clob object is valid for the duration of the transaction in which it was created.

A Clob isn't an object with the complete contents of the clob entry, it's an object that knows how to get the clob, that you can use to stream the contents of the clob to your application. This is similar to the ResultSet, which doesn't contain the data, it's something you use to retrieve the data. So the same way your resultSet goes away if you close the connection, the clob goes away when you close the resultSet.

The resources that get freed are things allocated by the database server in order for it to handle communicating with your JDBC objects.